# List of Pro Tools plug in suffixes

Tags: pro-tools, plug-ins

Anyone know of a comprehensive list of the suffixes that Pro Tools plugins tack onto the end of rendered files? For example: MH4T. What the heck plugin made that??

UPDATE:

OK, it seems that more than a few of you are interested in this topic and getting a glossary. Can someone get us started? Let's do it in the form of an answer to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: great idea, we could build a library of these suffixes!

Comment: Had a quick look in a special session for testing this. First thing to notice with Waves plugins is that mono and stereo have a different last letter: mono is 'N', stereo is 'T'. For C 1 Compressor this amounts to DNQN and DNQT. However, Avid plugins have no such difference between mono and stereo..

Comment: What we could do is crowd source this: create a session with 16 blank audio files for every one to download. Let everyone process those 16 files (mono and stereo) with different plugins and then upload the results to a google doc. We would have this done in 1 day when all SSD users help out.

Comment: A huge +1 to this, I'd love to know the same.  I'd certainly contribute.

Comment: fantastic idea, I'm in!

Comment: Dang, I created a spreadsheet of this with all the digi/waves plugins I had on hand back in DC. Let me search my backups and see if I kept it. Was actually pretty easy, just time consuming. Two tracks, one mono, one stereo. Render silence on each, duplicate x # of mono or stereo AS plugs you have. Process each dupe using each plug. Name each file the Manufacturer_Plugin_Mono/Stereo_FOUR LETTER CODE. File> Export> Session Info as Text.

Comment: Hi steve! You already did it all (digi ánd waves) that by yourself? great layout instruction!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking we break it by plugin bundles or something - so we don't get 10 WAVES gold submissions.  Maybe someone takes, if they got it, the iZotope stuff, someone take SoundToys, GRM, McDSP, Flux, SPL, Waves Mercury, etc?  That's the best idea I have so far on the topic.

I'm not sure of the best way to crowdsource the data and not get overburdened.  I already started an excel noting the ones I've used while cutting along the way.  I can compile the data from everyone so long as we can devide an conquer and have an efficient means to send the data over.

Maybe everyone, when they're done with their 'set', post a comment to this answer with a direct link to a TXT doc (or better yet, an excel doc).  Then I can just click-and-add to the master excel doc.

Here's what we're up against: http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/compatibility/en343311

Comment: Wow, that is a scary list. But, if anyone can tame it, its' the SSD crowd!

Comment: Indeed!  Eneryone, please shout out on here what plugin bundle you're taking so everyone knows!  None have been 'taken' yet.  Then post a comment with a download link to a TXT or excel doc (prefix "that" comment with "SUFFIX LIST >>>" so I can easily see which ones are the crowdsourced data versus the ones regarding who's got dibs on what bundle).  Thanks everyone!  For those know know my email (a few of you do), feel free to go ahead of a shoot me a message with what you got if you want.  Please don't upvote the comments below - I'll be using the upvote to note I already pulled your data in.

Comment: And as @Arnoud noted, please check to see if the suffix differs between a mono/stereo/5.0 etc version of the plugin.  If it does differ, please include all and note which is which.

Comment: I could do izotope rx3 and massey (incl. some functional demo plugs) in all formats (mono to surround flavours), ill edit this post with a link when i'm done.

Answer (score 0):

New contribution to an old thread…here's a partial list I put together, I'll just post it here and if anyone has a better method of displaying it / treating it as a "living" document that anyone can add to, please let me know.

In alphabetical order:

ASLF: Avid Lo-Fi

ASMA: Avid Maxim

ASSF: Avid Sci-Fi

ASST: Plug and Mix (P&M) - all plugs

ASRF: Avid Recti-Fi

AVrP: AudioEase Altiverb

BAAS: Avid Pro Limiter Loudness Analyzer

bpAS: GRM BandPass

coAs: GRM CombFilter

CRMB: SoundToys Crystallizer

CSAS: Avid Dyn3 Compressor/Limiter

CSSA: Channel Strip

ctAs: GRM Contrast

D1FN: Waves IR-L mono

D1FT: Waves IR-L efficient stereo

D1GT: Waves IR-L full stereo

D2DN: Waves C1 comp-sc mono

D2DT: Waves C1 comp-sc stereo

D3AS: Avid Dyn3 De-Esser

DaAs: GRM Delays, GRM Doppler

DCRM: Avid DC Offset Removal

DEC4: SoundToys Decapitator

DMBN: Waves H-Comp mono

DMBT: Waves H-Comp stereo

DNQN: Waves C1 comp mono

DNQT: Waves C1 comp stereo

DOUT: Waves Center

DPNN: Waves C1 comp-gate mono

DPNT: Waves C1 comp-gate stereo

Dvrb: Avid D-Verb

ECHC: SoundToys EchoBoy

EFRN: Waves C4 mono

EFRT: Waves C4 stereo

ELFa: Avid Eleven Free

eqAs: GRM Equalize

ESAS: Avid Dyn3 Expander/Gate

ETBN: Waves DeEsser mono

ETBT: Waves DeEsser stereo

EQBT: Waves Doppler

faAs: GRM Freeze

FF14: FilterFreak 1

FF24: FilterFreak 2

FOHT: Waves Enigma

fsAs: GRM Shift

fwAs: GRM Warp

GMON: Waves MetaFlanger

HB3N: Waves GTR Amp 2Cab mono

HBNN: Waves GTR Amp mono

HBNT: Waves GTR Amp stereo

HBUN: Waves C1 gate mono

HBUT: Waves C1 gate stereo

HD3N: Waves GTR Stomp 2 mono

HD3T: Waves GTR Stomp 2 stereo

HD5N: Waves GTR Stomp 4 mono

HD5T: Waves GTR Stomp 4 stereo

HDON: Waves GTR Stomp 6 mono

HDOT: Waves GTR Stomp 6 stereo

HWNT: Waves GTR Tool Rack stereo

ICEN: Waves H-Delay mono

ICET: Waves H-Delay stereo

INVT: Avid Invert

jcat: ReFuse Lowender

JESN: Waves IDR mono

JEST: Waves IDR stereo

LAB4: SoundToys Little AlterBoy

LSte: Avid Pro Limiter

M2DN: Waves L1 Limiter mono

M2DT: Waves L1 Limiter stereo

M3NN: Waves L2 mono

M3NT: Waves L2 stereo

M4HN: Waves L3 UltraMaximizer mono

M4HT: Waves L3 UltraMaximizer stereo

M4QN: Waves L3 MultiMaximizer mono

M4QT: Waves L3 MultiMaximizer stereo

MJN2: Waves L1+ Ultramaximizer stereo

MPA2: Spanner

PhzB: SoundToys PhaseMistress

piAs: GRM PitchAccum

PMN8: SoundToys PanMan

PnT2: Serato Pitch 'n Time Pro

PSA1: Avid SansAmp PSA-1

Psst: Avid Pitch II

raAs: GRM Reson

S4HN: Waves L3-LL Ultra mono

S4HT: Waves L3-LL Ultra stereo

S4QN: Waves L3-LL Multi mono

S4QT: Waves L3-LL Multi stereo

shAs: GRM Shuffling

SpVA: AudioEase Speakerphone

TiSh: Avid Time Shift

TRM4: SoundToys Tremolator

TUBN: Waves AudioTrack mono

TUBT: Waves AudioTrack stereo

VSPD: Avid Vari-Fi

XE3N: Waves Doubler2 mono

XE3T: Waves Doubler2 stereo

XE5N: Waves Doubler4 mono

XE5T: Waves Doubler4 stereo

xssa: Avid Mod Delay III

Z4C2: Izotope RX4 Decrackler

Z4D2: Izotope RX4 Dialogue Denoiser

Z4H2: Izotope RX4 Hum Removal

Z4K2: Izotope RX4 Declicker

Z4N2: Izotope RX4 Denoiser

Z4P2: Izotope RX4 Declipper

Z4V2: Izotope RX4 Dereverb